# Construct a function at runtime in C#

Tags: c#, lambda, runtime, compile-time, anonymous-methods

Lambda expressions are evaluated at compile time, so the below code will not generate a 100 different functions. Is there a simple mechanism to achieve the mentioned effect? I realize this isn't very efficient performance wise.

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    actions.Add(() => Execute(100100100 + i));
```

Comment: Of course, you can do something like [this](http://www.andymcm.com/blog/2009/09/building-lambda-expressions-at-runtime.html) but why do you need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code closes over a modified variable, so it's not going to do what you want it to do. You need to add a temporary variable for the value of `i`, like this:

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    int temp = i;
    actions.Add(() => Execute(100100100 + temp));
}
```

To create 100 separate lambdas, you can create LINQ expression to call `Execute`, build constants one by one, and compile the lambdas. However, this is unlikely going to give you much performance improvement. Here is how you do it:

```
var exec = typeof(Test).GetMethod("Execute"); // <<== Use your type here
var actions = new List<Action>();
for (int i = 0 ; i != 100 ; i++) {
    var val = Expression.Constant(i+100100100);
    // This assumes that Execute(int) is static.
    // For non-static calls use a different overload.
    var call = Expression.Call(exec, val);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(typeof(Action), call, new ParameterExpression[0]);
    actions.Add((Action)lambda.Compile());
}
```

[Here is a demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/xdjCrY).

Answer (score 2):

> Lambda expressions are evaluated at compile time, so the below code will not generate a 100 different functions.

I'm not sure what you mean by this statement. If you're trying to create 100 delegates, each bound to a different value of `i`, then you need to copy `i` into a temporary variable inside the `for` loop to ensure that the closures don't all refer to the same instance of `i`. (See 
dasblinkenlight's answer for details.)

But in this particular case, you can just use LINQ:

```
List<Action> actions = Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
    .Select(i => (Action)(() => Execute(100100100 + i)))
    .ToList();
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to use a loop and you're using .NET 4.5 or later, you can use `foreach` with `Enumerable.Range`:

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 100))
    actions.Add(() => Execute(100100100 + i));
```